# Can't Create Or Open Web Sites in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate SP1 x64

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have an error when trying to create  or to open a website in my visual studio professional 2012.

A dialog box appears to me that says says

> The Web Developer Tools option must be installed prior to opening or creating Web projects.You can install this option by repairing your Microsoft Visual Studio installation and ensuring that 'Web Developer Tools' is checked in the list of optional components

I am using  Windows 7  Ultimate Service Pack 1 on a 64-bit operating system and I have already installed the Web Developer Tools.

Could you please help me.

Comment: The error message looks pretty self explanatory to me. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have already installed this tool

Comment: The ERROR message is misleading - there is no option presented to change anything if you choose repair - its a completely automatic process without any user input.

Comment: Yeah my step 1 was "Repair", step 2 was StackOverflow.... I call bull on "not a real question"

Answer (score 24):

1. Go to `Control Panel` -> `Programs and Features` -> Select your Visual Studio Version and hit "`Change`".

[image]

2. Click MODIFY and enable `Web Developer Tools`

[image]

4. Enable `Web Developer Tools`

[image]

3. Click `Update`

Comment: Clicking 'Repair' does not solve the problem. You should click 'Modify' and then check the Web Tools box.

Comment: Someone should have edited this answer to avoid wasting 15 people's time waiting for it to repair unnecessarily.

Comment: I have updated it, the screenshots are for VS 2013 but for the purposes of this answer it's identical to 2012.

Comment: Also identical for VS2015, and I guess any VS since I recall they all have this option (starting vs2010 if I'm not mistaken)